# Can't edit 32 bit registry in C# (local machine)

Tags: c#, registry, regedit

The problem I am experiencing is when I add the code shown below it adds it to the 64 bit version of regedit. I want to the the below code to the 32 bit version because it seems not to be working in the 64 bit version.

Here is my code:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey keyyyyy;
keyyyyy = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList", true);
keyyyyy.SetValue("Sysaccounts", 0);
keyyyyy.Close();
```

Comment: You've got too much logic in the second sentence of your question.  Can you explain that a bit more clearly?

Comment: I also don't understand the last sentence.  You used too many pronouns.

Comment: Ive updated my question, i hope you will be able to understand my broken English now :D

Answer (score 2):

To use 32-bit view of the registry :

```
var regularx32View = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);

using (RegistryKey regKey32 = regularx32View.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList", true))
{
      regKey32.SetValue("Sysaccounts", 0);    
}
```

To use 64-bit view of the registry :

```
var regularx64View = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);

using (RegistryKey regKey64 = regularx64View.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList", true))
{
      regKey64.SetValue("Sysaccounts", 0);    
}
```

The name SysWOW64 is counter-intuitive. The 64 part in the name might (mis)lead someone into believing that it has 64-bit keys but in fact it has 32-bit keys.

Here's a relevant [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/305097/how-to-view-the-system-registry-by-using-64-bit-versions-of-windows)

Comment: Its still adding to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regedit.exe not regedit.

Comment: SysWOW64 is the 32-bit view of registry so that's the expected outcome. If you need to modify 64-bit view then see the edit to the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want this with more charm and more simple, take this:

```
RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
key.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Path1\Path2").SetValue("KeyName", "KeyValue");

string keyOutput = key.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Path1\Path2").GetValue("KeyName").ToString();
Console.WriteLine(keyOutput);
```

or

```
RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);
key.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Path1\Path2").SetValue("KeyName", "KeyValue");

string keyOutput = key.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Path1\Path2").GetValue("KeyName").ToString();
Console.WriteLine(keyOutput);
```

Enjoy